# Code Coverage using Visual Studio 2010 using VSTools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I wanted to use Code Coverage using Visual Studio 2010 ultimate edition.

My requirement is to have only vsinstr.exe and VSPerfCmd.exe available as part of VS tools.

I do not want to have share/install complete VS suite in a test machine however I am 
not getting any option to install only tools where vsinstr.exe and VSPerfCmd.exe files are available avoiding the complete installation.

Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this before and it seems to be able to work.  First, you need a machine with full VS 2010 ultimate installation. Then

1) copy this directory to your target test machine (one without VS2010):

\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools

vsinstr.exe/vsperfcmd.exe are found in this directory

2) run the tools as described here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2007/05/14/code-coverage-collection.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2007/05/03/code-coverage-instrumentation.aspx

It will then tell you a few .dlls are missing (namely, msvcr100.dll/atl100.dll/vscover100.dll).  The last one is found in the windows\system32\ directory while the first 2 are in the VS install directory. Just copy them to the target test machine.

3) Now from the target test machine copy the resultant .coverage, instrumented .pdb and .exe files back to your machine with a full VS ultimate installation plus your project directory, and open the .coverage file. Make sure the .pdb and .exe are present.

But there seems to be a problem. I was able to use the "Go to Source code" option in my Code Coverage Results window to navigate back to my source code.  But the source coloring 
option seems not working.  I am happy if you can try the above steps to see if you encounter the same problem.  Without src code coloring, code coverage results become difficult to interpret.

Comment: BTW, remember to apply Service Pack 1 to VS2010 since the source coloring is buggy in VS2010.